# disable jquery function for x seconds

Tags: jquery

I have an image with a jquery click attached to it

```
<img src=pic.gif id="action">
```

and some jquery

```
$("#action").click(function(){ 
    alert("DONE");
    });
```

How could I edit this so that the action function can't run for x seconds after it has ran? Say if I wanted it disabled for 5 seconds after each click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store the function in a variable. In that unbind the event and again attach it. This makes sure it will run only after the time period elapses..

Try this

```
var click = function() {
    $("#action").click(function() {
        alert("DONE");
        // Unbind the event
        $('#action').unbind();
        // Call the function after 2 second delay
        setTimeout(function() {
            click();
        }, 2000);
    });
    };
click();
​
```

Check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/Jgnxn/)

Comment: you don't need to wrap the `setTimeout` function in a closure, `setTimeout(click, 2000);` will do.

Comment: hopefully he doesn't want this functionality on other elements. This function is tightly coupled with `#action` but a good answer none the less.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an example, you may want to look into [Namespaced Events](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events) to prevent unbinding all `click` handlers.

```
var action_click = function(){
  var $self = $(this);

  alert("done"); // do your thing

  $self.unbind('click'); // unbind the click handler

  // rebind the handler after 5 second delay
  setTimeout(function(){
    $self.click(action_click);
  }, 5000);

};

// setup initial click handler
$('#action').click(action_click);
```

Example [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yHVsh/)